# 'provider.deploymentBucket': unrecognized property 'accessLog' error in Serverless.yml

Tags: yaml, serverless, serverless-framework, compiler-warnings

I have been trying to set the "Server access logging" for the deployment bucket in the serverless file with the following code:

```
deploymentBucket:
accessLog:
  bucket: !Ref BucketReference
  prefix: 'BucketPrefix'
```

The layout for the above code was found from using the "serverless-deployment-bucket", link [here](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-deployment-bucket).
But following the steps that has been laid out in the documentation throws the following error when deploying to AWS:

```
Warning: Invalid configuration encountered

at 'provider.deploymentBucket': unrecognized property 'accessLog'
```

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly